# Pass Data from modal popup to view in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have modal popup where I have two dropdowns and I need to pass the selected id's from modal popup to view on click of OK button.

Once, I clicked Ok button the modal should get closed and that related view should get open.

So, on view side I have created props to accept them like below

```
props: {
       
        id1: [String, Number],
        id2: [String, Number]
    },
```

And, from modal I am using the below code to navigate to the view page

```
 this.$router.push(
                    'someview/this.id1/this.id2'
                );
```

And I have also `props:true` for that related view to accept the parameters.

So, my question how can I hide that parameter value OR is there any different way it can be done

Thanks for the help !

Comment: what parameter you need to hide??
please elaborate with code

Comment: @tuhin47 I need to hide id1 and id2

Comment: you can set the parameters null or empty after the route happens

Comment: @tuhin47 Can you explain how it can be done ? What is best way to pass parameters from modal to view ?

Comment: you need to bind the parameter value with `v-model` from the modal. and after the click event occurs the bind values should be reset

Comment: @tuhin47 v-model i am using for dropdown data.. are you saying on modal level

Comment: please provide the component and modal code